# Problemas para iniciar máquina virtual con VirtualBox

Tags: virtualbox, genymotion, virtualización

Tengo un pequeño problema con VirtualBox.
Cada vez que quiero iniciar una VirtualMachine me aparece el siguiente error:

> "The Instruction at 0x12a15ae0 referenced memory at 0c12a15ae0. The
>   memory could not be written."

Si uso VMWare me funciona perfecto cualquier VM (Linux, Android, Windows, etc.)

La respuesta a por qué no utilizo VMWare, es porque necesito utilizar GENYMOTION, y entiendo que únicamente funciona con VirtualBox.

Alguna idea de porque me muestra ese error??

PD: Notebook Lenovo Windows 7 64 bits Intel core i5 8gb Ram

Comment: ¿No vi esta misma pregunta hace unos minutos desde otra cuenta?

Comment: Está eliminada esa pregunta :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tal ves se deba a que no tienes activada la virtualizacion de la bios en youtube puedes encontrar tutos para poder activarla